# Woocommerce remove free_gift from cart item count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have a function which sets a maximum order quantity of items in cart to 16. So user cannot checkout with more than 16 items.

I am also running a plugin which adds a `free_gift` key to the `$cart_item array` when a coupon is added.

The problem is that when a user adds 16 items + `free_gift` = the total is 17 items which prevents checkout.

How can I remove the `free_gift` from being added to the cart item count?

Example:

- Make Woocommerce cart think that 16 items + 1 `free_gift` = 16 items
- Make Woocommerce cart think that 12 items + 1 `free_gift` = 12 items

**My code so far, which allows free_gifts to be added over the max 16 limit, but does not apply the max rule of 16 items:**

```
    // Set a maximum number of products requirement before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_max_num_products' );
function spyr_set_max_num_products() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

        $cart_num_products = 0;

        foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            // HERE I AM TRYING TO SKIP AND PREVENT CART ITEMS OF FREE_GIFTS BEING COUNTED
            if ( isset( $cart_item['free_gift'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Count for regular products.
                   $cart_num_products++;
        }

        // Set the maximum number of products before checking out
        $maximum_num_products = 16;

        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total number of products
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines of
        // A Maximum of 16 products is allowed before checking out. (Cont. below)   
        if( $cart_num_products > $maximum_num_products ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Maximum of %s snacks are allowed per order.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of snacks: %s.',
                $maximum_num_products,
                $cart_num_products ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, that will remove your custom free item from cart items count:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'max_allowed_cart_items' );
function max_allowed_cart_items() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

        // Set the maximum number of products before checking out
        $max_items_count = 16;

        $cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count( );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( isset( $cart_item['free_gift'] ) ) {
                $cart_items_count -= $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        if( $cart_items_count > $max_items_count ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Maximum of %s snacks are allowed per order.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of snacks: %s.',
                $max_items_count,
                $cart_items_count ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the free item is in the cart. When it is you count the items "-1" in your function before the checkout is accessable.

```
    function free_product_in_cart($free_product_id) {

        $free_product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $free_product_id );
        return WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $free_product_cart_id ); //Return true when the free product is in the cart

    }
```

So then you update your logic to check:

```
 if(free_product_in_cart(your product id) { 
       $free_item_space = 1;
 } else {
       $free_item_space = 0;
 }

 if( $cart_num_products > $maximum_num_products + $free_item_space) {
        // Display our error message
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Maximum of %s snacks are allowed per order.</strong>' 
            . '<br />Current number of snacks: %s.',
            $maximum_num_products,
            $cart_num_products ),
        'error' );
    }
```

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding, but it looks like this will only work for a specific free item, based on the product ID? I need it to work for any `$free_gift` in the `$cart_item_array` as there are multiple free gift options.

Comment: Can you create an array containing the product ids for all free_items? Then you could just run the function for each array item